# Динамическое создание массива элементов input и их загрузка на сервер

Tags: jquery, php, html, javascript

У меня есть один `input type="file" name="files[]"`, а остальные создаются динамически. При нажатии на кнопку submit отправляется только тот `input type="file" name="files[]"`, который не был создан динамически! А остальные инпуты не видны. Почему? И как это исправить?

```
var massive = [];

function addNewInput(){

var ids = $("#divfiles input:file").last().attr("id");
var ind = ids.indexOf('_');
var ind2 = ids.substr(ind); 
    var ind3 = ind2.substr(1);
               var already_exists21 = 0;

var val = $("#fileinp_"+parseInt(ind3)).val();  
var index = val.indexOf('.');
var val2 = val.substr(0,index);
if(already_exists21 == 0)
{
    $("#choosingfiles").append('<span id="files_'+(parseInt(ind3))+'"><b>'+val+'</b><img src="../../images/delete_small.gif"        onclick="deleteFile('+(parseInt(ind3))+');" style="cursor:pointer;"></span>');
    var p = document.getElementById("divfiles");
    var y = document.createElement("input");
    y.setAttribute("type","file");
    y.setAttribute("name",'massfiles[file_'+(parseInt(ind3)+1)+']');
    y.setAttribute("id",'fileinp_'+(parseInt(ind3)+1)+'');
    y.setAttribute("onchange","addNewInput();");
    p.appendChild(y);
    $("#fileinp_"+ind3).css("position","absolute");
    $("#fileinp_"+ind3).css("top","-5000px");
    massive.push(val);
    var t = massive.join(',');
    $("#massfiles").val(t); 
}

}
```

**Добавлено.**

```
<div id="divfiles" style="display: block;">
                <input type="file" name="massfiles[file_0]" id="fileinp_0" onchange="addNewInput();" />

            </div>
```

Comment: @Va9im - уберите, пожалуйста, лишнее из кода, css стили, необязательные html элементы, комментарии и т.д. И назовите нормально переменные

       massive.push(val); // это LOL :)

Comment: это для другого немного... оно не лишнее... там снизу появляется имя файла который был выбран и рядом крестик для удаления импута с помощью которого был выбран этот файл

Comment: @Va9im - вы не поняли, название `massive`... Как-будто бы 1Сшник писал :)

Answer (score 1):

Я не уверен, но по моему любые манипуляции с файлами в браузере запрещены.
UPD: В том числе динамическое изменение. Добавление `type="file"`.

Comment: это реально... я точно знаю!!! А вот почему не получается хз((